# Using Javascript, how can I randomly offset for Longitude and Latitude numbers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I have an array of Longitude/Latitude numbers that I loop through to spit out markers for a Google Map. The markers I am using are circles to show a small area.  I am trying to "slightly" privatize the locations by offsetting the numbers by a small amount.  I am thinking fluctuations of +/- 0.001 to 0.009.

An example is: lat: 47.6204674, lng -122.3491156.

My current loop:

```
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
        // init markers
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
             map: map,
            icon: circleIcon
         });
    });
```

I need to modify item.lat and item.lng

thanks

Comment: Adding the random number in the client/browser won't prevent someone from getting the "real" number with a debugger.  If you want to protect the information, you need to do this processing on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in a random number in the range you suggest would work OK,

```
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        item.lat + ((Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0.001 : -0.009) + Math.random() * 0.008), 
        item.lng ...),
```

But for added anonymity, you might want to seed the random number generator based on the user ID.  Otherwise some hacker could invoke your code N times, take the average, and accurately work out the position.

Comment: That worked great.  Math.random (lowercase r).  thanks

Comment: Corrected in answer.  Thanks for that.  Upvote for you.

Comment: thanks so much!  I only found out becuase I got errors.  But I had no idea how to solve the issue.